# PlotRange -> Full giving the same result as with All for version 12.0

Tags: plotting, version-12

I have read all I could about `PlotRange`, but remain with this bug, and search for a workaround.

If I invoke (from the `Full` help page) on version 12.0:

```
Plot3D[Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

I get the same result as if I used `All` instead of `Full`; in other words, the plot range is restricted to the $[-1,1]$ range in both variables, even though `PlotRange -> Full` should plot over the range given in the input, i.e. $[-2, 2]$. On version 12.1 I see the difference.

As many of the computers I will use have not yet upgraded to 12.1, does anyone have a workaround for getting the correct behavior of `Full` (on version 12.0)?

Comment: I am also still on 12.0 and I see the same behavior you see in 3D; in 2D, however, `PlotRange -> Full` seems to work fine.

Comment: @MarcoB, thanx, I saw that as well in 2D. In the meantime, until I posted this question, I was scratching my head real hard, trying to figure what I had done to "break" `Full` in `Plot3D[]`.

Comment: @MarcoB, thank you for your edit.